# Should I strip turf or use weed killer?

Tags: lawn

I’m figuring out how to completely strip and replace my garden.

Do I need to hire a turf cutter, or can I can use weed killer to kill the lawn then rotovate it into the earth once dead?

Is one (a lot) better than the other?

Thanks

Comment: Your location helps us give you a better answer.  Some states/provinces are quite restrictive with allowing homeowners the use of herbicides

Comment: Instead of weed killer, have you considered solarizing?  It takes much longer, but does the same job in the end without chemicals.

Comment: Also, I very recently used a sod cutter. It is heavy and awkward but very effective. Sod is also heavy and awkward to move. When considering your options, remember that going this route will be quite a workout.

Comment: Where are you in the world and how large is the turfed area?

Comment: I’m in the UK, so - cold weather, no problem with using glysophate.

Comment: @SethMMorton I’d only go this route if the end result is going to be substantially better than weed killer or the journey a lot easier. If I use weed killer then rotovate, will I need to spend a lot longer picking out roots?

Comment: One thing that is not clear to me is what is currently in the area you want to replace, and what do you want to do with the area you want to replace.  Is it currently grass, or is it already garden but overgown in some sense? Do you want to end up with a flower garden, veggie garden, or something else?

Comment: Also, how big is the area?

Comment: Patchy uneven grass with what used to be flower bed borders but are mostly dead. About 10mx10m. I want to end up with a nice looking, flat grass garden with some low maintenance beds at the edges.

Answer (score 2):

I live in Souther California where devil's grass (warm season grass) needs to be removed with a sod cutter, but if you have cool season grass, why not try sheet mulching. It will smother the grass underneath, but also create rich soil in which to plant.

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward option is to spray the turf with glyphosate (Roundup, for example), wait seven days (assuming average temperatures) and then rotavate. If it's a large lawn, use a knapsack sprayer and also canes to mark out metre wide strips so you can spray methodically. Be aware that glyphosate is not a selective herbicide so avoid drift onto other plants. Chose a calm day and follow all manufacturer's instructions.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is my preferred approach. I don’t want to rent the cutter and have to deal with the turf, and there’s nothing out there we want to keep so no problem with protecting plants.